How do I integrate envoy as a gateway, auth0 as an authentication system and OPA as an authorization system?
I'm working on a server configuration with:

envoy proxy as a gateway, with a simple python web server behind it to serve web pages and API calls.
Auth0 to authenticate my users.
OPA as the Authorization system.

I've used a docker-compose.yml similar to this to create the envoy and OPA setup. I've implemented the Auth0 with OPA installation guide, so I have the Auth0 data in my encrypted session cookie after login (on which the authorization logic will work on). I've also found useful resources like this, that implement almost the exact flow I'm looking for.
All implementations, examples and guides I've found do not use this exact configuration, and have an additional piece of code that decodes the session data from the cookie, and extracts the user info (id_token) before calling the OPA service. Sometimes as part of the web server code (which defeats the purpose of the envoy gateway in my case).
I feel very close to an elegant design with little or no boiler plate code and with no overlap in responsibility between services. What am I missing? Is there an envoy filter that extracts the encrypted session from the cookie I should use before calling OPA? Perhaps OPA can decrypt the session data from the cookie?
Is there something inherently wrong in my design?

The best solution I came up with (especially in a docker-compose environment) is:

The standard Envoy Proxy docker image (envoyproxy/envoy)
The standard OPA docker image (openpolicyagent/opa)
The built-in Envoy OAuth filter (envoy.filters.http.oauth2). It would have been great if I could find an envoy OIDC implementation, but this ticket (https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/21982) suggests there isn't much interest in it. I'm not sure why... For a web based solution, the filter will route the IdToken from the authentication service, to the browser cookie.
The built-in Envoy External Authorization filter (envoy.filters.http.ext_authz) configured to point to the OPA service. This filter routes the cookie (with the IdToken) to the OPA service, allowing permissions based on user info from the auth service.
The built-in Envoy JWT filter (envoy.filters.http.jwt_authn), configured with remote_jwks to get authentication info directly from Auth0 (in my case)
Your backend services (web or API). They will not need any authentication / authorization logic.
An Auth0 account set up (in my case) for the envoy auth filter to work with. One might want to put user authorization data there.

In this solution, there is ZERO boilerplate code. No extra plugins to build into envoy, etc. Every component is separately configured using config files (OPA rego policy file, envoy yaml, and docker-compose to connect everything).
It was slightly difficult to find documentation to configure things correctly.
Please comment if you'd like me to share more details.

Looking at where the ID token is (and where you want it to be!) will help you solve this problem you have. I think you need to aim to have the token before making the OPA callout.
If you followed the guide here https://marketplace.auth0.com/integrations/styra-opa-authorization I believe you have ended up with your ID token associated with a session in your python backend (which is good security practice to keep it server side :) )
If you want the ID token to be handled by Envoy Gateway (effectively making Envoy Gateway your application backend, sort of a BFF, Backend for Frontend), you will have to do something along the lines of:

Set up OIDC with Envoy Gateway, making EG your OIDC Client of Auth0
On API call via EG, extract the ID Token from the cookie that EG populated to the browser as part of the OIDC flow
Populate the token on the OPA ext authz callout

Remember this type of implementation means Envoy Gateway is now your BFF and the OIDC Client to which the user has "logged in". EG now acts as an intermediary between your client side UI and your (ideally) stateless server side backend services.
You mentioned this is a monolithic app (i.e. the python web server both serves the UI and has all the APIs that the UI subsequently calls) - I would ask yourself what the motivation is behind making Envoy Gateway the OIDC Client App instead of your Python app? Is it easier to configure the callout to OPA with EG, than in the Python app? Maybe a monolithic Python app isn't your target architecture and therefore you want to do this at a unified Gateway layer? ;)

I'd like to add to this direction: an OIDC plugin is available here: https://github.com/dgn/oidc-filter (I haven't tried it, and it doesn't seem actively maintained, but worth noting).

I'm actually working on a micro-service oriented architecture, and started with one service, according to available documentation. I could not find a Auth0 + envoy guide, so I started with an implementation I can read and understand (the python backend). It is good as a learning exercise, but eventually, I've removed the Auth code from there and used a envoy's OAuth filter https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/oauth2_filter more details in my answer to myself soon.
